# Running Dart with Powershell not responding to Enter key - requires Ctrl D

Tags: windows, powershell, dart

My program:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
    stdout.write("Enter your name:");
    String? name = stdin.readLineSync();    
    print("Hello $name");
}
```

This program will not take the Enter key to end the input line.  I have to enter a Ctrl D and the Enter.

Sample output:

```
Enter your name:fred

^D
Hello fred
```

I am using Sublime for the editor and running Windows 11 with PowerShell but I get the same result with Command Prompt.

I have searched on line and watch several YouTube videos but they all show the same program structure.

Comment: If you get the same result with the Command Prompt, then it has nothing to do with PowerShell, does it?

Comment: FWIW, on my Windows 10 system, I can't reproduce your problem with either PowerShell or the traditional Command Prompt.

Comment: Thank you Robert for editing my post. It looked ok when I sent it.  I am new here and did not know I could edit it.  I have tried to run it with SDK 3.1 and 3.16 with the same result.  If the code works with Windows 10 (jamesdlin) it must be something with my Windows 11.